# Solr 8.8 - Search query with only date field year value

Tags: solr

I am using solr 8.8 . I have the index field "ds_date_updated", which has :"2021-03-22T12:40:44Z" format. Now I want to search with the 'ds_date_updated' field but only use the year. Is it possible?
I have tried https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_0/working-with-dates.html this.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of the field `ds_date_updated`? What query did you run against your collection?

Comment: Field type is date

Comment: In that case `ds_date_updated:[2021-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z}` should give you all entries for 2021. Pay attention to the use of `}` to denote an exclusive range at the end.